# LVDS CLK Input Appropriate Here?

Tags: circuit-design, clock, lvds

I'm working with an MCP37231/21-200 that requires a differential input for the clock. I need to know if I can use an LVDS input to drive my clock.  The output clock is specified to have LVDS capabilites, but the input clock does not state that.

[image]

[image]

From my understanding, LVDS inputs have a differential voltage of ~350mVpp, so it should work in this application. I'm also concerned about the common-mode voltage from the LVDS pair and the internally-generated common-mode voltage.

Would using an LVDS type signal be appropriate?

Comment: Do you have a choice as to whether to use LVDS or something else?  If you have a choice, LVPECL has better jitter characteristics than LVDS.  If you AC couple and terminate before the AC coupling, then LVDS should work fine.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. AC coupling saves me the most space anyways as opposed to the transformer-coupled Differential pair given as an example.